# How to securely code in Java?

Tags: java, secure-coding

I want to write **Java Desktop Applet** that is secure.

I know that user input validation is very important, but other than that, I have no idea what contributes to a secure java code. I tried looking for java vulnerabilities but the results are all relating to the java plugin. Please help

---

Edit:
I'm looking for secure coding resources specifically on java or cases where a java applet is compromised. So the first question is where can i find them?

The applet that i want to make involves peer-to-peer communication which consists of text, html and other files. Is it possible for one user to break into the applet of another user?

Comment: This is a very, very broad question. Try narrowing it down! What are you trying to code? What specific problem do you have when coding that?

Comment: What are your valuables? What exactly is it you need to secure? (PS: Use the **edit** button under your question to update it, and add more info).

Comment: In a well locked environment..

Comment: i've edited my answer to reflect your additions

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of resources on secure Java coding like [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)

Java is huge and exploits are complex. 
Your question is somewhat comparable to "How do i prevent my stuff from being stolen?"

What are your priorities? Where is it locked up? How big is it? What kind of people are you afraid of?

So to avoid this question being put on hold for being too broad, please tell us what exactly you're trying to build with java.

**edit:** your edit is a bit better, but not nearly specific enough.
I have provided you with a resource on secure java coding. In what way was that insufficient?

> cases where a java applet is compromised

The point of secure coding is to prevent compromise. After that, the damage is mainly contained by encrypting valuable data. Are you looking for that?

> Is it possible for one user to break into the applet of another user?

Here, your question sounds like "Can people break into my house?"

How could we possibly answer that without knowing details?
There are infinite ways to build what you're describing in a way that makes compromising it infeasible.
Likewise, there are even more infinite ways (har har) to screw it up and leave it wide open. That all depend on how you implement it.